# Vertex groups unwrapped properly in UV editing, but don't display the color properly

Tags: uv

I have a very simply UV unwrap of my character, with only two colors: Red and Black. I put one vertex group (the tie) into the red pixel of my texture, all the other vertices into the black pixel. First of all as can be seen in the picture below, no colors are showing up in the right window at all.
Secondly, when I go back to the Modeling tab, the tie is indeed somewhat red and the rest black, but the colors are not "sharp" (as in simply red or black like in the texture) but very soft and blended. Bigger faces, for example on the head, have a tint of red to them, kind of like the UV is not properly unwrapped.

Can anyone help me with these problems? It should be very simply to paint a model with only two colors, but I am unfortunately not getting the proper result. If there are any other good ways to paint simple low poly meshes, I am all ears. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hello! First of all you're in Solid mode, so are you sure you've enabled the Texture option in the Viewport shading options? Also, hard to understand the rest, maybe pack your images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Are all your faces assigned to a material that has redBlack.jpg as an image texture driving the color? Because even though you have your UV's unwrapped over the image in the UV Editor, it's ultimately the material that drives the color of the model's faces.